# Diablo 3 Multiple Characters

Tags: diablo-iii

I've just made a new character for my bf on Diablo 3 and he cant find Kormac in the cathedral, I was wondering if after your original character finds all the followers do you just not get them?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right place? Just follow the mainquest and you'll find him. Do note that he will nog stay in your party after his Quest is done in multiplayer.

Answer (score 5):

Once one of your characters finds a follower, all of your characters have them available so long as you are in the same game mode (i.e. hardcore, seasons, etc.).  Same goes for crafters (blacksmith, jeweler, mystic).

As @Arperum mentioned, you should still find a Templar in the cathedral as part of the story line (even if you have Kormac following you, you will temporarily have two followers until after Jondar).

Same goes for the scoundrel and enchantress (bringing along the same followers when meeting them for the second time can provide some funny/unique dialog by the way).  You will find a "second" follower of each for their part of the story.

Edit:  The followers are unique such that each of your characters will have to gear them differently.  I just tested creating a new character and the followers were available in both story and adventure mode (however they had default gear).

Comment: ... Don't think so, each character has their own followers (in contrast to crafters), at least the last time I played D3.

Comment: you are right that the followers are unique as far as their gear goes.  Each character's followers will be geared uniquely for each character.  Perhaps I was thinking about adventure mode unlocks them (It's been a while since I've created a new character!).  I'll update accordingly.

Comment: A scoundrel and an enchantress together are the best dialogue in the whole game.